# Load the value of a route dynamically in Sanic at startup

Tags: python, sanic

I want to do an asynchronous HTTP call to an external service at server startup and get an URL from there which I can then use in my own Sanic routing. E.g., fetch the string which needs to be my actual route via an `httpx` call (for the sake of simplicity, let's say the string returned by the external service is `api/users/`) and then use it as a route in my Sanic microservice.

Unfortunately it seems a `before_server_start` listener does not do the trick, as that is run after routes are loaded and I get a `FinalizationError("Cannot finalize router more than once.")` if I try to update the string value of a route.

Any ideas of how else I could hook up my call before defining / adding routes? I would like to keep it as coupled as possible to the Sanic app, i.e., not use a utility script that would run before it, but instead have the call to the external service triggered every time the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it inside the `before_server_start` event with a little roundabout.

```py
@app.before_server_start
async def setup_dynamic_routes(app, _):
    app.router.reset()

    # add your routes here

    app.router.finalize()
```

Comment: In following sanic version
`
sanic==23.3.0
, sanic-routing==22.8.0
`
When routes added  in `@app.before_server_start` between `reset` and `finalize` invoked , throwing below error
`AttributeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'response_middleware'`